# How do I get an array from PHP and use the values in the array?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I have a dropdown menu and javascript inside index.html. For clarity I removed most of the options (there're over 20). It sends the dropdown menu selection to `engine.php`

**index.html**

```
<script>
function refreshpage(e)
{   
    var e = document.getElementById("sr");
    var snk = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    window.location.href = "engine.php?selectedOption=" + snk;
}
</script>

<h4>Select your option</h4>
    <form action="" id="optionform" onsubmit="return false;">
        <select class="item_options" id="sr" name='sr' onchange="refreshpage(this);">
             <option value="None">Select option</option>
             <option value="Option1">Option 1</option>
             <option value="Option1">Option 2</option>
             <option value="Option1">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

---

When you select an option, it sends the option to engine.php

**engine.php**

```
<?php
$option1 = 5;
$option2 = 10;
$final = array($option1, $option2);
if($_GET["selectedOption"] == 'Option1')
{
    $option1 = 20;
    $option2 = 20;

}
?>
```

How can I send `$final` back into index.html and use javascript to use the values in the `$final` array (`$option1` and `$option2`). I basically want to refresh `index.html` and use the new, updated values (`$option1 = 20; $option2 = 20;`)

Comment: You can use a combination of `ajax` and `json_encode`

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax as @Hackerman suggested and is likely the approach I would use.

Alternatively, you can add a redirect to the end of your engine.php page and send the user back to the index page.

```
$newURL = "index.php?values=$newValues";
header('Location: '.$newURL);
```

To take this approach, your index page will need to process the values argument upon load.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care what the URL is you can `require` the *index.html* in your *engine.php*:

```
<?php
$option1 = 5;
$option2 = 10;
$final = array($option1, $option2);
if($_GET["selectedOption"] == 'Option1')
{
    $option1 = 20;
    $option2 = 20;

}
require('index.html')
?>
```

And so some PHP stuff in your *index.html*:

```
<script>
function refreshpage(e)
{   
    var e = document.getElementById("sr");
    var snk = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    window.location.href = "engine.php?selectedOption=" + snk;
}
</script>

<?php if ( isset($final) { print_r($final); } ?>

<h4>Select your option</h4>
    <form action="" id="optionform" onsubmit="return false;">
        <select class="item_options" id="sr" name='sr' onchange="refreshpage(this);">
             <option value="None">Select option</option>
             <option value="Option1">Option 1</option>
             <option value="Option1">Option 2</option>
             <option value="Option1">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

You can use `<?php ?>` tags anywhere, just remember this part will process on the server and send only HTML and JavaScript down to the browser.

Comment: I would need to change it from index.html to index.php, correct?

Comment: That may depend on how PHP is configure on your server. On my server all files are PHP parsed. Try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **ajax** instead to send data back and forth. With **jquery**, you'd do something like:

```
var final;
$.ajax({
    url: 'engine.php',
    data: { selectedOption: $('#optionform').find(":selected").text() },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        final = data;
    }
});
```

Then in `engine.php`, `echo json_encode($final);`

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done using AJAX.
Send AJAX to somepage.php where return json with $final.
After do something.

Comment: One way, but not the only way. How about an example?